# Is it possible to start an activity in background from a service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My activity have a .so that contain some c++ code. I need to run this code from a service, and i need to run it in background. it's really hard to move this code inside the service so i prefer to leave this code inside the activity.

Is their any way to start an activity in background and not in foreground ?

Comment: The service is part of your app or is in a different app? In first case you can move the code from the activity class to a utility class and call it from both the activity and the service.

Comment: the service is part of the app. how to make an utility class with c++ code and how to call it ?

Comment: How you call the c++ code right now from the activity? can you post the code?

Comment: all the activity is in a c++ .so file. I don't really know how it's call, it's part of the framework (ie: delphi)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not start an activity in background , to achieve what you need you have to use services .